# play/pause HTML5 video with spacebar in fullscreen makes error sound

Tags: jquery, safari, html5-video, html5-fullscreen

> **Important:** This was a bug in Safari 10 Public Beta

My code should do so the spacebar become a shortcut for playing/pause the video, but only when the user is having the mouse over the video, or are in fullscreen.

And it works!
But in fullscreen mode, it makes an error sound, why?

Here is my code:

```
objectVideo.hover(function(){
    $(window).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32) {
            playVideo();
        }
    });
});
```

if there is a better way or if you just know how to fix it I will be so happy

**NOTE:** Tested in Safari 10

Comment: Because you adding key event in player hover event. You should use key event handler along.

Comment: Oh thanks, but how to do so it's dosen't begin to play when the user not see the video in fullscreen?

Comment: You can call `playVideo()` on page load.

Comment: Still error sound :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you detect the mouse over the video outside the key handler, and then in the key handler just check if it's in fullscreen mode, or being moused over

```
var native = objectVideo.get(0);

objectVideo.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).data('isHovered', e.type==='mouseenter');
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
        var fullScreen = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
        var isHovered  = objectVideo.data('isHovered');

        if (fullScreen || isHovered) {
            native.paused ? native.play() : native.pause();
        }
    }
});
```

[**Example**](https://output.jsbin.com/luximaxifi)

Comment: Not sure, I tested it, and didn't get an error sound ?

Comment: try in fullscreen in safari?

Comment: on the otter site, it's also do that on facebook videos, maybe it's a bug

Comment: I've added an example that should work with fullscreen mode, for me there's no error sound when in fullscreen and hitting the spacebar

Comment: hmmm, then it must be a bug in the public beta version of safari